What is the point of this separate cryptography forum?
This forum only has 97 questions so far. What is the point? It is not visited by many people. Shouldn'it be re-intergrated with the main stackoverflow forum? I find it pointless.

Usually, it is considered polite to write a comment, if you downvote a question or an answer.

@bitmask: On the meta sites a downvote usually means "I don't agree", instead of "I think this question could be written better". There is no reputation here (all the reputation comes from the main site), and this is a discussion forum.

Okay, sorry then.

Now we've graduated I think it has become clear that this is a very viable site fortunately. And although we get the odd programming question we do have a pretty clear raison de etre - in my opinion that is. And I reiterate the welcome extended to you by Paŭlo Ebermann of course.

Welcome on Cryptography Stack Exchange!
From https://crypto.stackexchange.com/about:

This is a free, community driven Q&A for software developers, mathematicians and others interested in cryptography. It is a part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A websites, and it was created through the open democratic process defined at Stack Exchange Area 51.

For comparison, https://stackoverflow.com/about:

Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A site that’s free.

(Emphasis by me).
This site has a different topic - it is about cryptography, not about software development. While these topics sometimes overlap, they are still different. Here is the space for the more theoretical point of view.
This site was created at Area 51 - this means there were quite some people who showed interest in a separate cryptography site.

This forum only has 97 questions so far. [...]  It is not visited by many people.

Yes. It is new (created about a month ago), and there are not many questions yet, and not many users. We hope it will grow. It will always stay small compared to Stack Overflow, but this is not necessarily bad. We hope to get some more experts (other than Thomas) which will give high quality answers to high quality questions.

I find it pointless.

You are not obliged to come here (though we do appreciate if you do - you seem to be at least a bit knowledgeable in the field).
I'm sorry to have initiated the migration of your answers on Stack Overflow here (together with the questions) - but these questions were clearly fitting here better than Stack Overflow.

Shouldn'it be re-intergrated with the main stackoverflow forum?

If it shows that the site will not gain enough momentum to survive on its own, this might be considered. But most questions here will be better at IT Security - Stack Exchange than at Stack Overflow, if at all. (One could say this is more of a split-off from security than from Stack Overflow.)

I would also note that some subsets of the questions could be considered more of a split-off from [cstheory.se]... See the arguments back on [a51]...
